# how to send plain test email from campaign builder

Tags: email, infusionsoft

How can I create plain text emails within 'Campaign Builder'? I can't see a way to turn off HTML.

It is possible to create plain text emails within the 'Templates' interface. But that interface differs from the one within 'Campaign Builder' and strangely, it is not possible to import a plain text email from 'Templates' into 'Campaign Builder'. It is, however, possible to import a HTML email though.

Can someone explain why this is or how to create plain text emails for use within 'Campaign Builder'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Further research uncovered this information on the InfusionSoft forum:

http://community.infusionsoft.com/showthread.php/18071-Plain-Text-Template?p=44114&viewfull=1#post44114

"Note that pure, plain text emails are not available in the campaign builder. And, plain text emails cannot be tracked for open rates."